# is my data corrupt if during file transfer the external hard drive keep disconnect and reconnect?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8

So during file transfer , the external hard drive keep getting disconnect and reconnected. Windows shows the pop up error but when i press "Try Again" it continue the file transfer as normal.

is my data corrupt or it will be okay ? I haven't touch the data since transfer finish because i'm not a tech expert and i'm afraid to do wrong , please help me and guide me.

Answer (score 0):

Use any checksum generator to compare the integrity of your copy target by comparing the checksum of your source and your target file.

What is maker and model of your external hard drive?
Is it a 2,5'' drive without proper power supply?